# What's happening with FromDigits?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I thought I knew how FromDigits works, but it's doing something crazy now.

```
n[[990;;]]
FromDigits[n[[990;;]]]
```

outputs:

```
{9, 50, 0, 50, 1, 50, 2, 50, 3, 50, 4, 50, 5, 50, 6, 50, 7, 50, 8, 50, 9}
1405060708091011121309
```

instead of, you know, 950050150...

what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "string hacking" might be what you are asking for. This

```
myn = {9, 50, 0, 50, 1, 50, 2, 50, 3, 50, 4, 50, 5, 50, 6, 50, 7, 50, 8, 50, 9};
ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[myn], ", " -> ""]][[1]]
```

gives you this integer

```
9500501502503504505506507508509
```

That turns your list into a string, replaces each comma space separator with nothing, turns that resulting string back into an integer and discards the now unneeded curly brackets.

Comment: That works too, thanks.
I was just kind of hoping there was a more direct (one command) way of doing it.
I'm still trying to figure out if I like Mathematica (which I've been using on and off for a while, never really sitting down to learn thoroughly, but really wanted to like) or Python (which I JUST took an online intro course in and which thus far seemed much less frustrating than Mathematica)

Comment: Just imagine there was a unique Mathematica function name for every possible idea that everyone on the world wanted to do in their life. How would you ever find a catalog big enough to hold all them or to find the one that you wanted. And on your second point, every language has a learning curve. Mathematica is a very very different kind of language, even the things you think you know how they work are probably actually doing something very different under the surface. I suggest finding a really good book that matches your style and use that to learn the "Mathematica way of thinking."

Answer (score 7):

Documentation says that

```
FromDigits : constructs an integer from the list of its decimal digits.
```

So each number in the array must be less that 10 (decimal digits) for a simple concatenation.

Digits larger than the base are "carried": For example

```
FromDigits[{7, 11, 0, 0, 0, 122}] will give 810122
```

For more information go to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html

Comment: i see ... is there a way to concatenate numbers in list in the way that I meant?

Comment: As Solarmew says: `FromDigits[Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ n[[990 ;;]]]]`

Answer (score 1):

A couple other ways..

```
     FromDigits@Flatten@IntegerDigits@
        {9, 50, 0, 50, 1, 50, 2, 50, 3, 50, 4, 50, 5, 50, 6, 50, 7, 50, 8, 50, 9}
```

9500501502503504505506507508509

```
     (ToString /@ # // StringJoin // ToExpression) &@
        {9, 50, 0, 50, 1, 50, 2, 50, 3, 50, 4, 50, 5, 50, 6, 50, 7, 50, 8, 50, 9}
```

9500501502503504505506507508509